# Checkbox state on toggle?

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, toggle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#CO_createAccount").toggle(
        function(){
            $(".CO_accountForm").show('slow');
        },
        function () {
            $(".CO_accountForm").hide('slow');
        }
    );
});
```

Tried several methods presented here in SO for showing the checkbox state, but it's not working for me.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toggle is used to show/hide an element.

To get the state you can either use the jquery attr("checked") method or use the HTML DOM property checked.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#CO_createAccount").click( function (){ 
        if(this.checked){
            $(".CO_accountForm").show('slow');  
        } else {
            $(".CO_accountForm").hide('slow');  
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: follow up question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255139/make-show-hide-accessible-if-javascript-is-off - How do I make this accessible (show hidden element when javascript is turned off?)