# make show/hide accessible if javascript is off

Tags: jquery, accessibility, toggle, hide, show

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#CO_createAccount").click( function (){ 
        if(this.checked){
            $(".CO_accountForm").show();  
        } else {
            $(".CO_accountForm").hide();  
        }
    });
});
```

and I have the css set for ".CO_accountForm" set to "display:none;"

But, I want the hidden element to be visible if javascript is turned off. I assume I can do this by adding a hidden class the above, but how would I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `display:none` attribute for the `".CO_accountForm"` and instead hide/set the `display:none` attribute via javascript in the `document.ready` event.

i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
    // hide the form using JS so that if the browser 
    // doesn't support JS then the form is always displayed.
    $(".CO_accountForm").hide(); 
    $("#CO_createAccount").click( function (){          
        if(this.checked){             
            $(".CO_accountForm").show();           
        } else {             
            $(".CO_accountForm").hide();           
        }     
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks again. Much appreciated. These are basic functions that I should understand, so I need to beef up on my jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a <noscript> tag around the form in question? This would ensure that the form is displayed since you wouldn't be able to fire off any javascript anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Have element visible by default-- but add a class through jquery which hides them.